# Dplyr Filter Multiple Like Conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf

I am trying to do a filter in dplyr where a column is like certain observations.  I can use sqldf as

```
Test <- sqldf("select * from database 
          Where SOURCE LIKE '%ALPHA%' 
          OR SOURCE LIKE '%BETA%' 
          OR SOURCE LIKE '%GAMMA%'")
```

I tried to use the following which doesn't return any results:

```
database %>% dplyr::filter(SOURCE %like% c('%ALPHA%', '%BETA%', '%GAMMA%'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can use `grepl` with `ALPHA|BETA|GAMMA`, which will match if any of the three patterns is contained in *SOURCE* column.

```
database %>% filter(grepl('ALPHA|BETA|GAMMA', SOURCE))
```

If you want it to be case insensitive, add `ignore.case = T` in `grepl`.

Answer (score 6):

`%like%` is from the `data.table` package. You're probably also seeing this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In grepl(pattern, vector) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The `%like%` operator is just a wrapper around the `grepl` function, which does string matching using regular expressions. So `%` aren't necessary, and in fact they represent literal percent signs.

You can only supply one pattern to match at a time, so either combine them using the regex `'ALPHA|BETA|GAMMA'` (as Psidom suggests) or break the tests into three statements:

```
database %>%
  dplyr::filter(
    SOURCE %like% 'ALPHA' |
      SOURCE %like% 'BETA' |
      SOURCE %like% 'GAMMA'
    )
```

Comment: This worked perfect with my dataset and matched sqldf, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Psidom and Nathan Werth's response, for a Tidyverse friendly and concise method, we can do;

```
library(data.table); library(tidyverse)
database %>%
  dplyr::filter(SOURCE %ilike% "ALPHA|BETA|GAMMA") # ilike = case insensitive fuzzysearch
```