# filter with any wildcard element from list

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I filter rows using dplyr with wildcard elements from list. Like in below in below df

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("axyzr",
"bmnoc", "dbcdg", "hejd", "hsjj"), class = "factor")), .Names = "x", row.names = c(NA,
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to filter using below list

```
> fltr <- c('xyz','mno','bcd')
```

Something like

```
> df %>% filter(x %like% fltr)
```

And get

```
x
1 axyzr
2 bmnoc
5 dbcdg
```

Comment: `df %>% filter(grepl(paste(fltr, collapse = '|'), x))`

Comment: There are multiple duplicates for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759180/filter-by-multiple-patterns-with-filter-and-str-detect  OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057246/dplyr-filter-multiple-like-conditions Or a more general one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-using-a-character-vector-with-multiple-patterns